# Getting text from a URL using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using soup.get_text() but it is giving me the output as metadata.

```
url = "bit.ly/2DrYyhH"

r = requests.get(url)
print(type(r))

html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(type(soup))

print(soup.title)
text = soup.get_text()

print(text)
```

Output:

```
if ( typeof pmc !== 'undefined' && typeof pmc.hooks !== 'undefined' ) {
    pmc.hooks.add_filter( 'pmc-adm-set-targeting-keywords', function( keywords ) {
        try {
            if ( typeof Krux !== 'undefined' ) {
                if ( typeof keywords['ksg'] === 'undefined' ) {
                    keywords['ksg']  = Krux.segments;
                }
```

Comment: I have tried with htmlparser as well

Comment: What is the text that you want to retrieve? `soup.get_text()` will retrieve all the page source, including javascript code that you included in your question.

Comment: I want all the text apart from metadata. Basically, I want to extract all the words from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get all the text from the url, except all `script`, `meta`, `link` and `style` tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

URL = "bit.ly/2DrYyhH"

r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

for text in soup.body.find_all(string=True):
    if text.parent.name not in ['script', 'meta', 'link', 'style'] and not isinstance(text, Comment) and text != '\n':
        print(text.strip())
```